# How to create a filtered graph from an OSM-formatted XML file using OSMnx?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

In Python, we can use a function `osmnx.graph_from_place()` and a filter `custom_filter='["waterway"="river"]'` to get a filtered graph.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place("isle of man", custom_filter='["waterway"="river"]') # download directly.
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_color='r')
```

I want to get a filtered graph from an OSM-formatted XML file from my disk, but the function [osmnx.graph_from_xml()](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.graph) does not support the parameter `custom_filter`. How to get a filtered graph from *.osm data?

This will just plot the whole *.osm dataset:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_xml("isle-of-man-latest.osm") # from disk.
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_color='r')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSMnx's `custom_filter` parameter lets you filter an Overpass query with OverpassQL to generate filtered raw data for graph construction. If you are loading a .osm file, then you are explicitly bypassing the Overpass query step to instead directly import a local file of raw data for graph construction. OSMnx constructs the graph from whatever raw data you provide it.

You have a couple options. First, you can use OSMnx's `graph_from_place` or `graph_from_polygon` functions directly to get your graph, instead of loading from a .osm file, if possible. Second, if you need to use `graph_from_xml` and want to filter it, you can filter it after you've constructed it:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# create a graph with more edges than you want
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive', simplify=False)

# filter graph to retain only certain edge types
filtr = ['tertiary', 'tertiary_link', 'secondary', 'unclassified']
e = [(u, v, k) for u, v, k, d in G.edges(keys=True, data=True) if d['highway'] not in filtr]
G.remove_edges_from(e)

# remove any now-disconnected nodes or subcomponents, then simplify toplogy
G = ox.utils_graph.get_largest_component(G)
G = ox.simplify_graph(G)
```

Comment: These two options work fine with a small area, how about a larger area? I tried to use `graph_from_xml` with the area of Berlin (.osm.bz2, about 90 MB) downloaded from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html). To create a non-simplified graph it took a rather long time in my machine.

Comment: Big graphs can be slow. Hard to say more without a complete minimal reproducible example and code timings. Sounds like a separate issue so I'd recommend opening a new question.

Comment: This results in `KeyError: 'highway'` so check if the key exists first and `utils_graph` used to be `geo_utils` i'm using `osmnx==0.11.4` just in case anyone gets into the same issue I had

Comment: v0.11.4 is very old. If you run into errors I'd recommend upgrading to a modern version.